# How to show the window “Add connection” from the extension for Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vspackage

I am developing extensions (*VSPackage*) for *Visual Studio*.

I need to show the window "Add Connection".

How can I do that?

I looked for it at *MSDN*, but nowhere found examples of work with such windows. Also the variant of displaying the window "Data Source Selection" can suit me. I do not need the window "Server Explorer".

Comment: What's "the window Add Connetion" supposed to be? Maybe you should add a screenshot.

Comment: http://s017.radikal.ru/i404/1509/41/944d9c0e7700.png

Comment: http://s016.radikal.ru/i335/1509/e6/4cec1557f3c6.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several IVsDataXXX interfaces, that can vary among VS versions. See these articles that I wrote long time ago:

[HOWTO: Using the Choose Data Source dialog of Visual Studio 2005 from your own code](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2007/MZ2007011.aspx)

[HOWTO: Get data sources, data providers and data connections from a Visual Studio 2005 add-in](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2007/MZ2007018.aspx)